# For which orthogonal matrices does the matrix exponential converge?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function, exponentiation, matrix-equations

Part (a)

For which 2×2 orthogonal matrices A does
$\large e^A=I+\frac{A^1}{1!}+\frac{A^2}{2!}+…$
converge?

Part(b)

For what A does the series converge to an orthogonal matrix?

My work:

Let A be 2x2 and orthogonal.  Then $A^tA = AA^t = I$ and so this implies that A is normal.  Over the ground field = $C$, A is then orthogonally / unitarily diagonalizable.

We can write $A=QDQ^*$, where Q is unitary and D is diagonal with the eigenvalues of A on the diagonal.  Also, since A is assumed to be orthogonal, then the modulus of each eigenvalue is 1.

Now $$e^A=I+\frac{A^1}{1!}+\frac{A^2}{2!}+…$$

$$ e^A=I+\frac{QDQ^*}{1!}+\frac{QD^2Q^*}{2!}+…$$

$$ e^A= Q(I+\frac{D}{1!}+\frac{D^2}{2!}+…)Q^*$$

$$ e^A= Qe^DQ^*$$

Where $e^D$ is again diagonal.

What can I say from here?  I know that online sources such as Wikipedia and Wolfram just state without any proof or extended discussions that the matrix exponential is well-defined and converges for any square matrix.  If this is stated as a fact without proof, then it seems a little strange that I am working on a problem statement that asks "for which orthogonal 2x2 matrices A does $e^A$ converge".  Is there an important point that I am overlooking?  Or can I really just state that the matrix exponential converges for any square matrix A, hence it is well-defined and converges for *any* 2x2 orthogonal matrix A?

Any suggestions and hints for how to finish part (a) and how to start on part (b) are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: Your calculation is sufficient for the case you're given. You don't need to appeal to a general result, even though it is nice. What does your calculation say?

Comment: Hi @ThadJanisse, thanks for the quick response.  Well, I think that in concluding my answer, I need to address the issue of whether the $e^D$ matrix actually converges, but this is clear since it is just $diag(e^{\lambda_1}, ..., e^{\lambda_n})$.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: That's exactly right.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much @ThadJanisse.  On to part(b) ...

Comment: Is it allowed to use property that $e^{A} \cdot e^{B} = e^{B} \cdot e^{A} = e^{A+B}  \iff \lbrack A, B \rbrack = 0$?

Comment: Hi @Evgeny, I think that's fine to use.  Would this be for part(b) of the question?  That would be very interesting to see.  Thanks :-)

Comment: Yes, I thought about part (b) when I was asking this. It's easy to see that $(e^{A})^{T} = e^{A^T}$. You want $e^A$ to be orthogonal, i.e. $e^A \cdot e^{A^T} = e^{A^T} \cdot e^A = I$. From the property follows that $e^A \cdot e^{A^T} = e^{A+A^T}$. Now you can conclude what matrix should be $A + A^{T}$ if it's exponent is $I$ :)

Comment: Hi Evgeny, are you assuming that A and $A^t$ commute?  That would imply that A is normal, and I don't think we are allowed to assume that.  Though that could be one case to prove, and then to consider other cases, e.g., A not normal, A diagonalizable / not diagonalizable.  Or, did you mean something else with your solution, which possibly covers *all* cases of A?  Thanks,

Comment: However, take my advice with caution. I need to check is the property that I'm referring to is really true.

Comment: It seems that I've made a mistake. Most books only have statement $\lbrack A, B \rbrack = 0 \Rightarrow e^A e^B = e^B e^A = e^{A+B}$.

Comment: Hi @Evgeny, I'm just expanding out some of your work on paper and now see that, *assuming* that $A$ and  $A^t$ commute (so A is normal), then [A+$A^t$] = [0], in order to achieve the identity matrix I.  This shows that $A^t$ = -$A$, and so we can conclude that for any *anti-symmetric* normal matrix A, the series $e^A$ will converge to an orthogonal matrix.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Although I am not saying very much ...for an answer to the question.  There are a bunch more cases to cover.  I will re-read your comments now to see what else I can derive...thanks so much @Evgeny :-)

Comment: It is the right answer (because any orthogonal matrix is an exponent of skew-symmetric matrix), but at least we have to prove that zero matrix is **the only** real matrix which exponent gives identity matrix. As you might know from complex analysis, $e^z = e^{z + 2 \pi k i}$ so it's not always true that from $e^{z} = e^{w}$ follows $z = w$.

Comment: Hi @Evgeny, I think I see what you're saying.  So, basically, *force* the answer to be anti-symmetric, normal matrices, by first assuming that A is normal.  Then to show that it is the *only* possible answer and that there are no other cases to cover, just simply show that the zero matrix is the only matrix that yields the identity matrix, when we exponentiate it.  But that is already clear, since the zero matrix is trivially diagonal, and $e^{[0]}$ is just $diag(e^0, ... , e^0)$ = [0].  What do you think?  Would you say that it is pretty much a complete answer to part(b)?  Thanks,

Comment: Oh, no...sorry, @Evgeny, I did not show that other matrices do not yield the identity matrix, when exponentiated... hmm...

Comment: The biggest assumption that we have here is that from $e^{A} \cdot e^{A^T} = e^{A^T} \cdot e^A$ follows $e^{A} \cdot e^{A^T} = e^{A+A^T}$. Using Jordan decomposition it's not really hard to prove that zero matrix is the only **real** matrix which exponent equals identity matrix.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much @Evgeny :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I know that online sources such as Wikipedia and Wolfram just state without any proof or extended discussions that the matrix exponential is well-defined and converges for any square matrix.*

$\quad$ Every matrix has an element of maximal size. $($Obviously, if *anything* can cause

divergence, it's *that* one$).~$ Let its absolute value be $M.~$ So let us construct a square

matrix *S*, whose every single element is $M.~$ Then $S^k=\Big(n^{k-1}M^k\Big)_{n\times n}~,~$ and each

element of $A^k$ lies between $\pm~n^{k-1}M^k.~$ But $~e^S\approx\bigg(\dfrac{e^{nM}}n\bigg)_{n\times n}~,~$ so every element

of $e^A$ is definitely *bounded*. However, even in this case divergence could still theoret–

ically happen, if at least one such element $($not necessarily the same$)$ were to freely

oscillate inside a given range, without actually converging to any particular value

within that interval. But this is not possible, since each new term of the infinite series

decreases at an [exponential rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation), being trapped between $\pm~\dfrac{n^{k-1}M^k}{k!}.$

Comment: Hi @Lucian, can you please elaborate on how you arrive at $n^{k-1}M^k$ in your first equation?  And how does the approximation of $e^S$ show the boundedness of $e^A$?  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames: Just take a simple $2\times2$ or $3\times3$ matrix, and square it. What do you get in each cell ? $M\cdot M+M\cdot M+\ldots+M\cdot M$, *n* terms in total, meaning $n\cdot M^2$. Multiply it again by itself, and see what happens. Also, it goes on without saying, that if some terms were smaller than *M*, and positive, then the sum of products would be smaller than $n\cdot M^2$. And if they are negative, and less than *M* in absolute value, than it's even “worse”, since they not only add less, but outright cancel the contribution of the other positive terms.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much @Lucian :-)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the series for $e^A$ is easy to prove using matrix norms.  In particular, you should try to prove the inequality
$$
\left\|e^A \right\| \leq e^{\|A\|}
$$
if $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm (such as the Frobenius norm) which satisfies $\|AB\| \leq \|A\| \cdot \|B\|$ for all matrices $A,B$.

---

It is, in fact, a well known result that a matrix $A$ will be such that $e^{tA}$ is orthogonal for every $t \in \Bbb R$ if and only if $A$ is skew-symmetric, which is to say that $A^T = -A$.  This is a commonly used result in the context of Lie Groups and Lie Algebras.

At the very least, you should try to prove that if $A^T = -A$, then $e^A$ is orthogonal.

I am not sure whether there are any other matrices $A$ for which $e^A$ is orthogonal.

---

A matrix $A$ such that $e^A$ is orthogonal but $A\neq A^T$:
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\0&2\pi i}
$$
or better yet
$$
\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 4 \pi^2 & 0}
$$

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom, yes, with the help of Evgeny (see the comments in this question post), I was able to show that requiring A to be anti-symmetric yields an orthogonal matrix exponential $e^A$.  However, we needed to make a pretty big assumption, I think:  we assumed that A was normal, so that A commutes with its transpose - this allowed us to use the exponential rule $e^Ae^{A^t} = e^{A+A^T}$.  Setting this equal to the identity matrix forces A to be anti-symmetric. I don't know of any other way to provide a proof, without this assumption.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Thanks as usual for your answer :-)

Comment: @LebronJames Orthogonal matrices do commute with their transpose, because a matrix is orthogonal iff its orthogonal is: $AA^\top=I=A^\top A$.

Comment: Hi @anderstood, yes agreed.  But what I am asking is really this:  if $e^Ae^{A^T} = e^{A^T}e^A$, then this shows that the matrix exponentials commute -- but from this, must $A$ and $A^T$ *also* commute?  If they do, then my proof is complete.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: I think it's an interesting question. Jordan normal form doesn't help, but Schur decomposition might.

Comment: See my latest edit. Still not sure how to classify all such matrices, though

Comment: Slightly more generally, if $a \ne c$, 
$$\exp\pmatrix{a & b\cr 0 & c\cr} = \pmatrix{e^a & \dfrac{b (e^c - e^a)}{c-a}\cr 0 & e^c}$$
so this gives an example of a non-normal matrix whose exponential is normal if $a \ne c$ but $e^a = e^c$, i.e. $c - a = 2 \pi i n$ for some nonzero integer $n$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Well, all sources that are known to me have the statement in form "$\lbrack A, B \rbrack = 0 \Rightarrow e^A e^B = e^B e^A = e^{A+B}$". I think it means that there is some counterexample to the statement $e^B e^A = e^A e^B = e^{A+B} \Rightarrow \lbrack A, B \rbrack =0$. Also, the real assumption that I suggested Lebron James to make is that from $e^{A} e^{A^T} = e^{A^T} e^{A}$ follows $e^{A} e^{A^T} = e^{A+A^T}$.

Comment: For a **real** example where $e^{A} e^{A^T} = e^{A^T} e^A$ but $e^A e^{A^T} \ne e^{A+A^T}$, try $$ A = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & -2\pi\cr 0 & 0 & 2\pi & 0\cr}$$

Comment: @RobertIsrael Great, thank you very much! It also would be very interesting and educational (at least for me) if you have shared the insight that helped to find this example :)

Comment: @Evgeny if you have a complex matrix that you want to make real, replace the entry $a+bi$ with the block
$$
\pmatrix{a&-b\\b&a}
$$
an oldie, but a goodie.  I've also added a real example of my own to the end of my answer.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Wow, I forgot about this trick :) thanks!

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom, I read up a little bit on your last comment - turning a complex matrix into a real matrix, and going from a complex entry into a 2x2 real block.  (I computed an explicit example a couple nights ago, but very mechanically.) Apparently, this change from a complex matrix to a real matrix is an operator isomorphism.  Does this automatically mean that if the complex matrix is invertible, then the corresponding real matrix is also invertible?  And if the complex matrix is similar to another complex matrix, then the two corresponding real matrices will again be similar?

Comment: The notes don't mention this after stating that the change from complex to real is an isomorphism, so I am just wondering whether you have a quick, intuitive answer to offer.  Thanks, @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom -- I'll actually post this as a new question on MSE now.  Thanks,