# Why is this exponential bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A$ be a square real $n\times n$ matrix whose eigenvalues have real part $\leq 0$.

Let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_l$ be eigenvalues of $A$ whose real part is zero. Suppose that for each $1\leq j \leq l, nullity(A-\lambda_lI)=multiplicity(\lambda_l)$.

How do I prove that $|(e^{At})_{ij}|$ is bounded when $t\in [0,\infty)$?

I know that $(e^{At})_{ij}=p(t)e^{\lambda_l}$ for some polynomial $p$, but I don't think this leads the result.

Comment: Do you know the Jordan canonical form of a matrix?

Comment: @mathematician Oh right.. I proved it. So the strategy is to bound eigevenvalues with $Re=0$ then bound eigenvalues with $Re<0$ right?

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477541) question.